# How to retain current tab after submit and jumpmenu - jQuery,PHP, html

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

How do you retain current tab after refresh,submit and jumpmenu using jquery. if its too troublesome, I don't mind using PHP and sessionstorage. but please don't use cookies. BTW, im not good in jquery. Below is example and extract. I also don't know why the jquery is greyed out below.  I don't mind using PHP if jquery is causing too much trouble. tq. Please help.

(useracc-test.php)

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 jQuery(function($) {

    $("<p>").html("Loaded at " + new Date()).appendTo(
        document.body
    );
    showTab(location.hash || "Tab 1");

    $("#nav a").click(function() {
        var hash = this.getAttribute("href");
        if (hash.substring(0, 1) === "#") {
            hash = hash.substring(1);
        }
        location.hash = hash;
        showTab(hash);
        return false;
    });

    function showTab(hash) {
        $("div.tab").hide();
        $("#tab-" + hash).show();
    }

}); 




<link href="SpryAssets/SpryTabbedPanels.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryTabbedPanels.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_jumpMenu(targ,selObj,restore){ //v3.0
  eval(targ+".location='"+selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value+"'");
  if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="apDiv3">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="TabbedPanels1" class="TabbedPanels">
  <ul class="TabbedPanelsTabGroup"  id="nav">


    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Tab 1</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Tab 2</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="TabbedPanelsContentGroup">
    <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">
      <p>


      </p>







      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">
      <form name="form2" 
      action="useracc-test.php" method="post" >
        <p>&nbsp;</p>

        <table width="500" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td>category</td>
            <td><select name="jumpMenu" id="jumpMenu" onChange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
              <option value="useracc-test.php">Category</option>
              <option value="useracc-test.php">Type1</option>
              <option value="useracc-test.php">Color</option>
              <option value="useracc-test2-jumpmenu.php">Type2</option>
              <option value="useracc-test2-jumpmenu.php">Hobby</option>
            </select></td>
```

here below, i update another example from the internet. How do i change this and apply to my tab?

```
  $('ul.tabs').each(function(){
    // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
    // which tab is active and its associated content
    var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

    // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
    // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
    $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
    $active.addClass('active');

    $content = $($active[0].hash);

    // Hide the remaining content
    $links.not($active).each(function () {
      $(this.hash).hide();
    });

    // Bind the click event handler
    $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
      // Make the old tab inactive.
      $active.removeClass('active');
      $content.hide();

      // Update the variables with the new link and content
      $active = $(this);
      $content = $(this.hash);

      // Make the tab active.
      $active.addClass('active');
      $content.show();

      // Prevent the anchor's default click action
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

Comment: you have to save selected tab id in cookies or local storage.On page refresh check saved value and change selected tab

Comment: tq Muhammad. i read many example with explanaton  only on the internet. but cannot find any solution. can you show me how  in the answer section? I understand the concept but cannot figure out the algoritma.tq

Comment: can you show me example how the jquery works using tabs?tq

Comment: if possible. i just want simple jquery without cookies. because, some website disable cookies. i just want jquery only.

Comment: I never expected this question to be extremely dificult.It seems no one here knows the answer. :-(

Comment: i already read all the examples on the internet. but the examples shown is not suitable or not easy to understand on the internet. can anyone show me an easy example from scratch so that i can apply on my website. i just need easy example only. tqs. this is getting frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function showTab(hash) {
            localStorage.setItem("hash", hash);//save hash value in localstorage
            $("div.tab").hide();
            $("#tab-" + hash).show();
        }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (localStorage.getItem("hash")) {//check if value exist
            showTab(localStorage.getItem("hash").toString());//set the saved tab
        }
    });
```

Comment: tq muhammad..for helping me. alhamdulillah. but i already tried ur sugesstion but all the jquery function greyed out (everything is grey) in my page?. did i put the jquery in the wrong section?

Comment: can you please upload your code at https://jsfiddle.net/? it will be easy to solve your issue

Comment: oo..ok..tq Muhammad. tqs for the suggestion.

Comment: I went to jsfiddle. It is extremely difficult to understand the website.

Comment: I don't know where to begin. And i don't know how to post a question in jsfiddle.

Comment: can anyone teach me how to post question in jsfiddle. im feeling im inside MSDOS when i go to fiddle.

Comment: @LindaMay update question and post full page code.You have posted half page

Comment: Hi Muhammad can you show me a BASIC example how to retain current tab after refresh etc. Please show a basic code including the tabs, then i will learn from there.  tq.